# Getting text between the beginning of a paragraph and a specific link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to find a way to get the text between the beginning of a paragraph and a specific link using jQuery:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">aliqua</a> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna <a href="#">aliqua</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

In this case, for example, if my element is the first link, I need to get the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliqua
```

I already have the link as an element, let's call it *e*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to filter the text based on whether the children elements/text nodes have a previous `a` element. For instance:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/kwkjz2y8/)

```
var text = $('p').contents().filter(function () {
  return !$(this).prevAll('a').length;
}).text();

console.log(text); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliqua
```

- The `.contents()` method returns all the children elements and text nodes.
- The `.filter()` method iterates over everything that `.contents()` returned.
- The element or text node is included in the set of filtered items if there *isn't* a previous `a` sibling element. This means that all the text nodes before the first `a` element **and** the first `a` element will be included in the filtered set.
- The `.text()` method is chained to retrieve the text of all the returned, filtered elements and text nodes.

---

The code above will merely return the text in the first link and the text before it. If the anchor element isn't always first, you can simply add a class to it. For instance, if we add the class `.target` to the specific link, then you can use:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ny4n44zz/)

```
var text = $('p').contents().filter(function () {
  return !$(this).prevAll('a.target').length;
}).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  
  var desiredTag = $("<p>"+$("p").html().split("</a>")[0]+"</a></p>").text();
  alert(desiredTag);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">aliqua</a> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna <a href="#">aliqua</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

1. `$("p").html().split("</a>")[0]` gives `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">aliqua`.
2. Append `</a>`.
3. Wrap it in `<p>...</p>` and make it a jQuery object.
4. Fetch it's text.